# How to redirect the user back to the originally requested page with Auth0?

Tags: owin, nancy, auth0

I'm using Auth0 with OWIN and lock.js as described in [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/server-platforms/aspnet-owin). The only difference is that I'm using Nancy instead of MVC, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Logins are working correctly. **Now I would like to be able to redirect the user to the page that he originally requested, i.e. the URL he entered when he was redirected to the login form.**

I can't find any information in the Auth0 tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The answer by Eugenio pointed me into the right direction, I post the complete solution here as reference.*

The return URL needs to be stored in the `state` parameter. The Auth0 OWIN package supports redirection after successful logins, **but requires the redirection URL to be named `ru` in the state parameter**.

So this is how the Lock setup will look like:

```
lock.show({
    // Other lock setup params
    authParams: {
        state: 'ru=RETURN_URL_HERE'
    }
});
```

Comment: 1 year later, i think this has changed, its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is to save the original URL in the `state` parameter, which the protocol (OpenID Connect) guarantees it will be preserved throughout all transactions.

In nodejs/passport you would do:

```
//Middleware for routes that require login:
var requiresLogin = function(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
            var orignalUrl = encodeURIComponent(new Buffer(req.url).toString('base64'));
            return res.redirect('/login?state=' + orignalUrl);
        }
...
```

and then in the callback URL:

```
app.get('/callback',
    passport.authenticate('auth0', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
        function(req, res) {
            if (!req.user) {
                throw new Error('user null');
            }

            if(req.query.state){
                var orignalUrl = new Buffer(decodeURIComponent(req.query.state), 'base64').toString();
                return res.redirect(orignalUrl);
            }

            res.redirect("/");
});
```

et voila!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it didn't work for me. The reason was that the configuration seems to have been changed to the constructor instead of the `show` method. Also, there were different things I needed to do in order to make it work, like setting an `auth.params.state` property, an `auth.redirectUrl`, and an `auth.responseType` property. In the link below I describe in a better way how I solved it. I was developing a React application with React Router, however the solution I describe is somewhat general.

https://github.com/auth0/wp-auth0/issues/29#issuecomment-252040395