# Redirect back to original URL after registration with auth0

Tags: php, registration, auth0

Our customer hosts online and in-person educational courses. My company has created a website for them that allows visitors to browse the catalog of courses and sign up for them. We're now working to implement authentication using auth0 to integrate our website with the customer's new SSO solution.

User registration and login work, but there is a requirement made by project management that we have so far been unsuccessful to implement. The scenario:

> A new user visits the website and finds a course they want to take.
> They click on "Register for this course". Since they are not logged
> in, they will now be redirected to the Log In/Register page. They sign
> up for a new account. After completing the registration process, they
> should be redirected back to the page of the course they originally
> came from.

The auth0 workflow is set up in such a way that after completing the multi-step registration process (which includes e-mail verification and entering a code sent to the user's mobile phone), the user is redirected to a "continue" page ("customer-site.com/our-site/continue").

At this point however, we lack the information which course page the user originally initiated the registration process from, since the "continue" page apparently isn't provided any parameters (contrary to what the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41477293/auth0-application-redirect-back-to-original-url-in-apache-webapp) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33865627/how-to-redirect-the-user-back-to-the-originally-requested-page-with-auth0) claim, we do not receive a state parameter — is there possibly an issue with the way our customer's auth0 workflow is set up?).

The way we went about this: we encoded our state information and passed it to the `login` method of auth0:

```
$auth0->login(base64_encode($my_state));
```

At the end of a regular login, auth0 redirects the user to our *callback* page and the state parameter is present and contains the data we provided (`$my_state`).

If the user performs a registration instead, they are redirected to our *continue* page, which doesn't receive a state parameter. This redirection to *continue* happens after the user confirms their e-mail address, the url looks like this:

```
https://<our-page.com>/continue&supportSignUp=true&supportForgotPassword=true&email=<user e-mail>&message=Your%20email%20was%20verified.%20You%20can%20continue%20using%20the%20application.&success=true&code=success#&language=de
```

We have read [auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/authenticate/login/redirect-users-after-login) detailing similar topics (actually redirection after login, not registration), which recommend using cookies for this. However, project management requires a solution that doesn't require the use of cookies.

Since the SSO infrastructure is owned by our customer, we can't make changes to the auth0 settings directly, but we can make requests.

Is it possible to redirect users after registration to the page where they were before initiating registration? Is it possible to do so without the use of cookies?

Comment: _"we do not receive a state parameter — is there possibly an issue with the way our customer's auth0 workflow is set up?"_ - who is creating the login URL the user is send to? Was a `state` parameter actually included at this point?

Comment: @CBroe We use the method `$auth->login($state)` of the auth0 PHP SDK, that's how we provide the state information. Please see also the edits I made to the question.

Comment: I don't think that's correct, the login method appears to expect the redirect URI as first parameter, and an array of additional parameters as second, if I am reading https://github.com/auth0/auth0-PHP/blob/99950202ea3de2737638eaf137c16c7ae70bc809/src/Contract/Auth0Interface.php#L42 correctly.

Comment: @CBroe For PHP compatibility reasons we're using version 7.5 of auth0-PHP, the interface seems to have changed since then. Please compare https://github.com/auth0/auth0-PHP/blob/7.5.0/src/Auth0.php

Comment: _"If the user performs a registration instead, they are redirected to our continue page"_ - redirected not by the SDK / the OAuth flow, but by your own application? When the user arrives on the redirect URI, and there you determine that they do not have an account yet? In that case, it sounds like you neglected to pass the state parameter the redirect URI received, on to your continue page ...? That won't happen automatically, you'll have to append it to the new URL you are redirecting to yourself.

Comment: @CBroe The redirection to the "continue" page is performed by the SDK/flow. This was set up on the customer's side; we were required to name a URL that is going to be called as a workflow continuation in case of registration or password reset

Comment: _"performed by the SDK/flow"_ - do you have some more details on that? AFAIK, OAuth itself doesn't provide a way to specify multiple different return URLs.

Comment: @CBroe Our website code only passes the redirect URL (callback) to the auth0 SDK. I believe the "continue URL" after registration is a setting of the auth0 application, possibly the setting called "Application Login URI". Our code does not provide that URL to the SDK and does not link to it directly.

Comment: You wrote _"This redirection to continue happens after the user confirms their e-mail address"_, so this doesn't seem to be part of the OAuth flow itself at all ...? If this all happens on "their" side, then why don't they store the current URL from which the user triggered the whole thing into a session, and then fetch it again from there after they return from the whole process?

Comment: @CBroe I'm not sure if I understand you correctly - the redirect happens when the user clicks on the "confirm e-mail address" button on the page that the "confirm your e-mail address" e-mail sends them to. Is that not part of the OAuth flow?

Comment: Nah, I don't think so. The point of OAuth in general is that you get user data from a provider who is already "trusted", so if they have an email address stored for your user, then you should be able to assume that they, the provider, have already verified it. If your customer has implemented an additional "confirmation" of that email address for some reason, then likely that is happening outside of the OAuth flow.